# Undefined function, MYSQL error

Tags: php, mysql

When submitting the following form I am getting this error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in .... mailing_list_include.php on line 7

Here's the mailing_list_include.php file - the real thing includes the correct credentials for accessing the db

```
<?php

function doDB() {
global $mysqli;

// connect to server and select database; you may need it
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username",
    "password", "db");

    // if connection fails, stop script execution
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
}
}

function emailChecker($email) {
global $mysqli, $check_res;

//check that email is not already in list
$check_sql = "SELECT id FROM SUBSCRIBERS
    WHERE email = '".$email."'";
$check_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $check_sql)
    or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you verified that you have mysqli installed?

Comment: No, haha! Simple, I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means your copy of PHP was not compiled with [mysqli support](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.requirements.php).  This doesn't mean there is anything wrong with your code, you are simply trying to use a function that PHP does not have available.

See [Installation - Mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php) on PHP.net for more information on configuring it.  You will have to ask your host if they can rebuild PHP and include mysqli support.

Answer (score 2):

[Installation of the mysqli extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php)